# Flutter 2 action buttons in different position

Tags: flutter, button

From my project

[image]

I've tried with Stack but it s not working for me, how can I add 2 floating buttons in different positions? One in the top left and one in the bottom center.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
floatingActionButton: Column(
  children: [
    IconButton() // button 1
    IconButton() // button 2
 ])
```

Comment: OK, it works somehow but how can I position them one topstart and one bottom center?